# SQL Server Compact в net.Core.App приложении

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

Хотел использовать SQL Server Compact в приложении под Ms.Net.Core.App (.NetCore 3.1). Искал в Nuget, но нашел лишь под .NetFramework. У меня два вопроса:

1. Есть ли возможность использовать SQL Server Compact 4.0 в .NetCore 3.1?
2. Если на 1-й вопрос ответ - "нет", то какие компактные базы данных использовать в приложении .NetCore 3.1?

Comment: [это?](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40)

Comment: @tym32167  В документации написано: "Этот провайдер в основном предназначен для настольных приложений в .NET 4.6.1 (Console, WPF, WinForms и Services), но может также работать в ASP.NET 4.6.1 и ASP.NET Core 2.0 при использовании полной среды выполнения .NET Framework. ***Он не работает в среде выполнения .NET Core.***"

Comment: Тогда вариантов у вас немного. Я бы поглядел в сторону [SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite)

Comment: @tym32167 А я бы поглядел в сторону [LiteDB](https://www.litedb.org/)

Comment: Оба варианта норм. LiteDB я использую на работе. Ну как использую. Написал и оно уже пару лет живёт и не меняется.

Comment: Вообще, кстати, используй EntityFrameworkCore в связке с тем же SQLite или отдельно можно использовать LiteDB.